# Show FCM notification thoughout the app when the app is open (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to send push notifications to my device right now and it's working perfectly. However when the app is open, I only get the onResume to be executed when I'm in that particular page. I want to display the notification on the top regardless of which page(or class) the user is on. **Basically I want the notifications to be displayed globally (Show popup). Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code from the page that displays the notifications.**

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
     iosSubscription = _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((data) {
    _saveDeviceToken();
   });

  _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
} else {
  _saveDeviceToken();
}

_fcm.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    var temp = message['notification'];
    setState(() {
      title.add(temp['title']);
      body.add(temp['body']);
    });
   
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: ListTile(
          title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
          subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            color: const Color(0xFF650572),
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MessageHandler()));
    // TODO optional
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MessageHandler()));
    // TODO optional
  },
);
```

}

Comment: Did you managed to fixed it. I am also struggling with the same. Can you share the working code as answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your MaterialApp in a wrapper class ... lets call that FCMWrapper.

```dart
class FCMWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const FCMWrapper({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FCMWrapperState createState() => _FCMWrapperState();
}

class _FCMWrapperState extends State<FCMWrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<YourObservable>(
      builder: (context, yourObservable, _) {
        if (yourObservable != null && yourObservable.isNotEmpty) {
          Future(
            () => navigatorKey.currentState.push(
              PushNotificationRoute(
                  child: YourViewOnNotification(),
              )),
            ),
          );
        }
        return widget.child;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have stored my data in an observable from a separate class. So when I receive a notification I update my observable. Since we are consuming on that observable the PushNotificationRoute would be called.

PushNotificationRoute is simply a class which extends ModalRoute.

```dart
class PushNotificationRoute extends ModalRoute {
  final Widget child;

  PushNotificationRoute({this.child});

  ... //Override other methods to your requirement

  //This is important
  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return child;
      }),
    );
  }

  ...
  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 200);
}
```

Now in main.dart declare a global key like

```dart
var navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

and wrap your MaterialApp like

```dart
...

FCMWrapper(
          child: MaterialApp(
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            title: 'Your App',

...
```

So now every time a notification comes in your observable should update and push a modal route which would be shown over anywhere in the app.

Comment: Wow this is awesome. couple of things i want to know. Can you please tell me in which file you have added these codes or any sample code. I am also facing issue. I am not able to show the alert on message or on resume. Also facing issue while decoding the message.

Comment: Honestly, this seemed like a hassle, I just ended up using the local_notifications package.

Comment: @ThatGuy I am even struggling with local_notifications package. It is giving me hard time. You must have seen my question. it is still not working.